# How to dispaly registered username as subdomain in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, dns

I have referred other related questions/threads but they are not clear to me. Please explain/help me: How can I dispaly registerd username as subdomain in wordpress ? Ex. if user register with abcd user name then abcd should be display as sub domain like abcd.example.com and rest part of url point accordingly.

I have already configured DNS record as wildcard like "*.example.com  A ip-address" and subdomain is also pointing to main domain's IP addrerss but there is
calling/loading anonymous/blank page, while it should be point to main domain's index.php if there is not mentioned any specific page in url.

Here is site htaccess codes:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteBase / 
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L] 
</IfModule>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does it output anything? Have you got error reporting turned on? Have you tried with just a near-blank index.php (with say "echo 'hello';") to make sure all domain mapping is correctly setup? Also, apache or nginx? Probably should show your apache conf and ngxin config

Comment: you want just add manually a word to example.com or you want to code that username should take it to domain name.if you want to add just abcd.example.com than it could be done using .htaccess

Comment: @Chris  - thanks for reply, yes error reporting is ON , i have just uploaded a blank index.php with some custom text and it is echoing with site url only but not with subdomain url. yes it is apache .
Site url: [http://virtualmdoffice.com/] and subdomain url: [http://pawan.virtualmdoffice.com/] . i didn't find where it is pointing.

Comment: @MudassarSaiyed Saiyed  , No i want to code dynamically logged username will added in url.

Comment: @PawanSingh So we can safely ignore all things wordpress. Something is up with your apache2 confg. Can you post that

Comment: @Chris - which specific configuration you want see in apache 2 . so that i can ask to my server administrator.

Comment: Assuming debian/ubuntu - `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/[site-conf].conf` and also the `.htaccess`

Comment: @Chris - .htaccess codes 
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
and about "[site-conf].conf" will tell you very shortly. thanks

Comment: Please update the question (easier to read as you can format it with code that way)

Comment: @Chris -  My apologies, perhaps i didn't get you, what i need to change in my question ?

Comment: Hi. Just post the contents of the htaccess file and the config (.conf) file to your original question (and use the code format button). It will make it easier to read

Comment: @Chris - Hello , Hosting providers says they can't provide me whole config file , do you want to see any specific configuration(name) in config file ?

Comment: It would be just the bit that sets this particular site up. If you're with a hosting provider that won't provide config details, there is very good chance you won't be able to do it on such a host (you will need to check with them if they support dynamic subdomains)